# Aspnet Core - Error 400 When i send Httpost with js

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I need to get a list `permissao` when I select a group, I made the methods but when I select the group, it returns me an error.

> PermissaoGrupo/ObterPermissoesAdd:1 Failed to load resource: the
>   server responded with a status of 400 ()

**View**

```
@model RKMES.Models.ViewModel.PermissaoGrupoViewModel
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/plugins/forms/inputs/duallistbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/pages/form_dual_listboxes.js"></script>
<h2>Index</h2>

<div class="form-group">
    @*<label asp-for="Grupos" class="control-label">Grupo</label>*@
    @*<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Grupos,"Id","Nome"))"></select>*@
    Grupos
    @Html.DropDownList("Grupos", new SelectList(Model.Grupos,"Id", "Nome"))
</div>
<!-- Filtered results -->
<div class="panel panel-flat">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5 class="panel-title">Filtered results</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        @*<select multiple="multiple" class="form-control listbox-no-selection" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Permissoes,"Id","Nome"))"></select>*@
        @Html.DropDownList("Permissoes", new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Id", "Nome"))
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /filtered results -->
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Grupos').change(function () {
            var idGrupo = $('#Grupos').val();
            if (idGrupo > 0) {
                $.post('@Url.Action("ObterPermissoesAdd", "PermissaoGrupo")', { 'idGrupo': idGrupo }, function (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                            $('#Permissoes').append('<option value="' +data[i].Id+ '">' + data[i].Nome+ '</option>');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**PermissaoGrupoController**

```
    [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public IActionResult ObterPermissoesAdd(int idGrupo)
            {
                return Json(_grupoContext.GetPermissoesAdd(idGrupo));
            }
```

**GrupoService**

```
public async Task<List<Permissao>> GetPermissoesAdd(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Grupo_Permissao_Permissao
                .Where(x => x.Grupo_PermissaoId == id)
                .Select(x => x.Permissao)
                .ToListAsync();
        }
```

**Model**

```
namespace RKMES.Models
{   // essa é uma tabela intermediaria das entidades Grupo_Permissao e Permissao
    public class Grupo_Permissao_Permissao
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Grupo_PermissaoId { get; set; }
        public int PermissaoId { get; set; }

        public virtual Grupo_Permissao Grupo_Permissao { get; set; }
        public virtual Permissao Permissao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, it is caused by `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`. which will check whether the request contains `RequestVerificationToken` header.

For a quick test, you could remove `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` from Controller.

For a recommended way, you need to attach the anti forgery token like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var Group = {
            GroupId: 1,
            GroupName: "My Group Name"
        };

        AjaxPost("/Groups/AddGroup", Group).done(function () {
            GetGroups();
        });

    });
    function gettoken() {
        var token = '@Html.AntiForgeryToken()';
        token = $(token).val();
        return token;
    }

    function AjaxPost(url, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            responseType: "json",
            url: url,
            headers: {
                "RequestVerificationToken": gettoken()
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        });
    }
</script>
```